# Implementing a Fixed Coordinate system in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, matrix, openframeworks

The simple version of my project is rotating a sphere based on user input.

However my rotations get weird after multiple rotations in certain situations due to openGL's local coordinate system.
What I really need is to rotate based on a world/fixed coordinate system. Such that when I rotate the sphere once its rotation axes are not rotated as well.
This issue is explained here http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm at 9.070.

I understand all that.  However setting up what they suggest is a bit beyond my skill level.  Does anyone have any experience with this?  I tried using some code I found here
http:// chaosengineer.com/?cat=19
but had no luck.

Here is the basic code I am using.

```
glPushMatrix();

//draw in middle of the screen
glTranslatef(ofGetWidth()/2,ofGetHeight()/2,0);

glRotatef(xRot,1,0,0);
glRotatef(zRot,0,0,1);

glTranslatef(-ofGetWidth()/2,-ofGetHeight()/2,0);

ofSetColor(255, 255, 255, 255);
squirrelModel.draw();
glPopMatrix();
```

Answer (score 2):

YOu need to store object *orientation* as a matrix. Or as a set of vectors (local X, local Y, local Z).

To rotate object a bit, multiply orientation matrix by rotation matrix each time. Just make sure that all vectors of orientation matrix remain perpendicular to each other.

In this case, when rendering, instead of glRotate/glTranslate you'll need to use glMultMatrix.

Or use quaternions.

I understand it is not a complete answer, but (although I have written libraries and code for doing this), explaining this will take a lot of time.

Try downloading [NVidia OpenGL sdk](http://developer.nvidia.com/page/opengl.html) and see how they handled object rotation in their demos.
Also search for *3d orientation* with google. Some papers should explain how to store object orientation using matrices, and so on.

And check [euclidianspace.com](http://euclideanspace.com/maths/index.htm)